# Unity 5.1 audio issues (no sound in back channels)

Tags: unity, audio

I've trying to bring in surround sound audio into my project. I've set my computer up to run in 5.1 and when I play a 6 channel audio through windows media player (it's a test audio that does left speaker, right speaker etc) it works fine.

However, when I run it through Unity, all I get is the front 3 channels. I've set it in the Edit -> project settings -> audio to be 5.1 in there. I even set it in code with following:

void Start()
{
 AudioSettings.speakerMode = AudioSpeakerMode.Mode5point1;
}
How ever, when I run a debug line of:

print ( AudioSettings.driverCaps);
It tells me that Unity is only playing in stereo. Is there something I'm still not doing?

I should also add I've ran 10 different tests using the 3D audio pan and spread options. I've set both to either being fully off, half way on and full. Still the same results.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same symptoms. 5.1 I uploaded a channel's wave file to Unity, but it only plays in stereo. Unity mixer set to 5.1. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the [AudioSettings reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSettings.html), it says that **AudioSettings.driverCaps** gives the speaker mode *capability* of the current audio driver.  If the current audio driver is only *capable* of stereo playback, then that's why you aren't hearing 5.1.  Try debug printing the value of **AudioSettings.speakerMode** to see what's actually set.  The [speakerMode reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSettings-speakerMode.html) says: "If a speaker mode is set beyond the drivers capability, the audio behaviour is undefined."